# delete a page from my favorite list. (php)

Tags: php, list

My friend created a website with the capability to add pages to the user favourite list. but recently I got many complains about deleting one page from the favourite list... it looks like the code has an error and sometimes add pages instead of deleting pages.

more explanation : each page has a certain id so when adding something to the favourite it adds the id number and then it puts comma to separate other numbers. same thing with deleting a page from the favorite.. it searches for the number and deletes it ... but sometimes it does not ! I do not know why ... it tells me "the page was successfully deleted" but I donot see it deleted and sometimes it returns some old pages that I deleted before ! can you please check the code ..

here is the code

```
if($_REQUEST['do'] == 'delfav')
{
    $mn_Id = safe($_REQUEST['mn_Id'],true);
    $page  = 'favorite';
    if(isset($mn_Id))
    {
        $fav = explode(',' , $_SESSION['user']['Favorites']);
        if(in_array($mn_Id,$fav))
        {
            echo $ind = array_search($mn_Id , $fav);
            unset($fav[$ind]);
            $new = implode(',' , $fav);
            $ss = $db->query("UPDATE users SET Favorites = '".$new."' WHERE Id = '".$_SESSION['user']['Id']."' ");
            if($ss)
            {
                $msg = 'the page was successfully deleted';
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = 'error occurred please try again later';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = 'This page is not in your favorite list';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your friend should really not use nested CSV tables inside SQL tables.

Comment: Yes: `Your friend should really not use nested CSV tables inside SQL tables.`. Fix this before going live, then you can also delete stuff in pure SQL.

Comment: any chances of fixing the code without changing it ?

Comment: How would you fix code without chaning it?

Comment: I mean without changing the hall code.

Comment: can you give me a solution code !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't change the code related to database, you can test with the follow code instead:

(...)

```
if(isset($mn_Id))
{
    $fav = explode(',' , $_SESSION['user']['Favorites']);
    if(in_array($mn_Id,$fav))
    {
        $fav = array_diff($fav, array($mn_Id));
        $new = implode(',' , $fav);
        $ss = $db->query("UPDATE users SET Favorites = '".$new."' WHERE Id = '".$_SESSION['user']['Id']."' ");
```

(...)

Where the change was replacing this:

```
echo $ind = array_search($mn_Id , $fav);
unset($fav[$ind]);
```

for this:

```
$fav = array_diff($fav, array($mn_Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

From my previous experience - and as phresenel said - avoid using CSV inside ur tables. I don't know about the length of your lists but I've managed to break PHP strings several times. If you wish to keep your CSV (It is your <strike>funeral</strike> site), check that unset truly unsets the desired variable (echo the list after and before).
But if you wish to improve it, I suggest using a separate table for the favourites; a table that has only two columns, one for the used id and the other for the favourite web site (A four entries list will translate to four records - each with the same user id). To delete just search for the user id and web site, if found delete that row. To add, just add a new row. Note that this a very simplified approach that may violate several DB best practices.